# Problem with NetLogo anonymous procedures

Tags: lambda, netlogo, procedure, anonymous

i have problems converting old NetLogo Code to work with NetLogo 6.0.1

The line I am having trouble with is the following:

```
set recv turtle (read-from-string ?)
```

I know that ? has been changed to ->. But i can't figure out, how this line works.

The whole code is:

```
to send [msg]
  let recipients get-receivers msg
  let recv 0
  foreach recipients [
   set recv turtle (read-from-string ?)
   if recv != nobody [without-interruption [ask recv [receive msg]]] ;; read-from-string is required to convert the string to number
  ]
end
```

Comment: can you please show us the whole piece of code - where did the ? come from? For example, if this is in a foreach loop, show the foreach loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?` representing each element of `recipients` is now replaced by a local variable declared within the `foreach` brackets. Here, I've declared a variable `recip`, but it can be anything you want.

```
    to send [msg]
      let recipients get-receivers msg
      let recv 0
      foreach recipients [recip ->
       set recv turtle (read-from-string recip)
       if recv != nobody [without-interruption [ask recv [receive msg]]] ;; read-from-string is required to convert the string to number
      ]
    end
```

Two nice things about this: you can "name" the question mark, making it easier to remember what it stands for, and, if you are iterating over more than one list, you can declare more than one variable, one for each list.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please also help me with this part:

`to-report get-sender [msg]
  report remove "sender:" first (filter [not is-number? ? and member? "sender:" ?] msg) 
end`

Comment: It's the same idea. Just looking at `filter` piece, `filter [m -> not is-number? m and member? "sender:" m] msg`.  Having question marks be part of the names of the `is-number?` and `member?` primitive is another reason for getting rid of them to represent an item in the `msg` list.